# Parse JSON from Bittrex

Tags: python, json, urllib

I have this code:

```
import urllib2
import json
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime as datetime
import numpy as np
import csv

l = []
date = []
date_intermediaire = []

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-ETH&tickInterval=thirtyMin&_=')
data = json.load(response)
```

where `data['result'][:]['T']` contains the time, `data['result'][:]['V']` contains the volume ,`data['result'][i]['O']` contains the opens, `data['result'][i]['C']` contains the close,`data['result'][:]['L']` contains the low, `data['result'][:]['H']` contains the high

And actually I would like to make easier this defining r like this:

```
r['date'][i] = data['result'][i]['T']
r['open'][i] = data['result'][i]['O']
r['close'][i] = data['result'][i]['C']
r['max'][i] = data['result'][i]['H']
r['min'][i] = data['result'][i]['L']
r['volume'][i] = data['result'][i]['V']
```

But I don't know how to do this in Python.

Comment: This is already mostly valid Python code to parse a dictionary... What's the issue?

Comment: Looks like you have numpy.... do you also have pandas?

Answer (score 1):

you can work with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
...
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['result']) 
df.columns=['volume','close','max','min','open','date','last_column'] 
df.head()
```

output:

```
      volume     close       max       min      open                 date  \
0  19.949007  0.056340  0.056560  0.056302  0.056340  2018-03-29T02:00:00   
1  28.811991  0.056302  0.056540  0.056301  0.056350  2018-03-29T02:30:00   
2  17.516028  0.056170  0.056488  0.056150  0.056302  2018-03-29T03:00:00   
3  33.393220  0.056030  0.056450  0.056020  0.056450  2018-03-29T03:30:00   
4  29.046574  0.055430  0.056140  0.055300  0.056030  2018-03-29T04:00:00   

   last_column  
0   354.123891  
1   511.145471  
2   311.468766  
3   594.549165  
4   521.328565
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to "reduce" your data here. You could use [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) here, but it probably would be easier to just write your own function. Something that cycles over each result and appends it to the relevant column.

```
def map_response(data):
    retval = {
      'date': [],
      'open': [],
      # ...
    }
    for result in data['result']:
       retval['date'].append(result['T'])
       retval['open'].append(result['O'])
       # ...

    return retval
```

You could probably also automate this a little bit more by describing the mappings.

```
def map_response(data):
    mappings = {'T': 'date', 'O': 'open', '...': '...'}
    retval = {val: [] for val in mappings.values()}
    for result in data['result']:
        for key, value: result.items():
             retval[mappings[key]] = value

    return retval
```

But to me that looks less clear, just saves repetition.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't know what how to loop over the dictionary or list in the parsed JSON

```
results = data['result']
r = []
for res in results:
    value = {}
    value['date']= res['T']
     # TODO: Get other values 
    r.append(value)
```